# why is my app stalling when the play button is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, xcode6

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var timerCount = 5
var timerRunning = false
var timer = NSTimer()

func shuffle<C: MutableCollectionType where C.Index == Int>(var list: C) -> C {
    let c = count(list)
    for i in 0..<(c - 1) {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(c - i))) + i
        swap(&list[i], &list[j])
    }
    return list
}

func counting(){
    timerCount -= 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"
    if timerLabel.text == "0"{
        if timerLabel.text == "0"{
        timerLabel.text = ""
        self.youFailedView.image = UIImage(named: "youFailed")

        }



    }

}

var backRoundRand = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1


@IBOutlet weak var backRound: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var youFailedView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sign1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sign2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sign3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sign4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sign5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var color1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var color2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var color3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var color4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var color5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var blueButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var purpleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var orangeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yellowButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var redButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    var gameViewStillRunning = true
    var sign1RandNum = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1
         var sign2RandNum = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1
         var sign3RandNum = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1
         var sign4RandNum = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1
         var sign5RandNum = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1
    var colorArray = ["orangeBrick", "blueBrick", "yellowBrick",   "redBrick", "purpleBrick"]
    var shuffledColorArray: Array = shuffle(colorArray)
 self.color1.image = UIImage(named: shuffledColorArray[0])
self.color2.image = UIImage(named: shuffledColorArray[1])
self.color3.image = UIImage(named: shuffledColorArray[2])
self.color4.image = UIImage(named: shuffledColorArray[3])
self.color5.image = UIImage(named: shuffledColorArray[4])
    var correctAnswer1 = ""
    var correctAnswer2 = ""
    var correctAnswer3 = ""
    var correctAnswer4 = ""
    var correctAnswer5 = ""
   /*switch backRoundRand{
    case 1:
        self.backRound.image = UIImage(named: "redBack")
    case 2:
        self.backRound.image = UIImage(named: "greenBack")
    case 3:
        self.backRound.image = UIImage(named: "orangeBack")
    case 5:
        self.backRound.image = UIImage(named: "purpleBack")

    default:
        break
    }*/

    switch sign1RandNum{
    case 1:
        self.sign1.image = UIImage(named: "blank")
        correctAnswer1 = shuffledColorArray[0]
    case 2:
        self.sign1.image = UIImage(named: "forward")
        correctAnswer1 = shuffledColorArray[1]
    case 3:
        self.sign1.image = UIImage(named: "fastForward")
        correctAnswer1 = shuffledColorArray[2]
    case 4:
        self.sign1.image = UIImage(named: "backSpace")
            correctAnswer1 = shuffledColorArray[4]
        default:
        break
    }
    switch sign2RandNum{
    case 1:
        self.sign2.image = UIImage(named: "blank")
            correctAnswer2 = shuffledColorArray[1]
    case 2:
        self.sign2.image = UIImage(named: "forward")
            correctAnswer2 = shuffledColorArray[2]
    case 3:
        self.sign2.image = UIImage(named: "fastForward")
            correctAnswer2 = shuffledColorArray[3]
    case 4:
        self.sign2.image = UIImage(named: "backSpace")
            correctAnswer2 = shuffledColorArray[0]
    default:
        break
    }
    switch sign3RandNum{
    case 1:
        self.sign3.image = UIImage(named: "blank")
            correctAnswer3 = shuffledColorArray[2]
    case 2:
        self.sign3.image = UIImage(named: "forward")
            correctAnswer3 = shuffledColorArray[3]
    case 3:
        self.sign3.image = UIImage(named: "fastForward")
            correctAnswer3 = shuffledColorArray[4]
    case 4:
        self.sign3.image = UIImage(named: "backSpace")
            correctAnswer3 = shuffledColorArray[1]
    default:
        break
    }
    switch sign4RandNum{
    case 1:
        self.sign4.image = UIImage(named: "blank")
            correctAnswer4 = shuffledColorArray[3]
    case 2:
        self.sign4.image = UIImage(named: "forward")
            correctAnswer4 = shuffledColorArray[4]
    case 3:
        self.sign4.image = UIImage(named: "fastForward")
            correctAnswer4 = shuffledColorArray[0]
    case 4:
        self.sign4.image = UIImage(named: "backSpace")
            correctAnswer4 = shuffledColorArray[2]
    default:
        break
    }
    switch sign5RandNum{
    case 1:
        self.sign5.image = UIImage(named: "blank")
            correctAnswer5 = shuffledColorArray[4]
    case 2:
        self.sign5.image = UIImage(named: "forward")
            correctAnswer5 = shuffledColorArray[0]
    case 3:
        self.sign5.image = UIImage(named: "fastForward")
            correctAnswer5 = shuffledColorArray[1]
    case 4:
        self.sign5.image = UIImage(named: "backSpace")
            correctAnswer5 = shuffledColorArray[3]
    default:
        break
    }

    if timerRunning == false{
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning = true
    }


    if userAnswer != correctAnswer1{
        self.youFailedView.image = UIImage(named: "youFailed")
    }

}
var userAnswer = ""
@IBAction func blueButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    userAnswer = "blueBrick"
}
@IBAction func purpleButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    userAnswer = "purpleBrick"
}
@IBAction func orangeButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    userAnswer = "orangeBrick"
}
@IBAction func yellowButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    userAnswer = "yellowBrick"
}
@IBAction func redButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    userAnswer = "redBrick"
}



}
```

I am not sure why this code stalls the program when my play button is hit to move onto this scene. The play button is on my first view and I hooked up a segue on storyboard to go directly to this view controller when pressed. However, once the play button is pressed, nothing happens and it doesn't move on to this scene. Not sure why it is doing this, no infinite loops or reasons I see. Any suggestions? Also if anyone knew how to simplify some of this code that would be nice, I am a beginner and new to swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can profile the application to see which part of the code is taking a long time to execute, that will help you narrow it down.  Hold down on the run button and select profile.

Tap on "Time Profiler" from the menu that comes up.

[image]

Tap on the record button and you will see the app appear.

[image]

Hit the stop button in the profiler once you have encountered the slowness.  Highlight the peak that shows the consumption of execution time.

[image]

You will then be able to see the methods that were called and what took so long to execute during that time.

[image]

Expand the methods on that screen to figure out what part of your code is causing the slowness, you can then optimize it to make it quicker or move it into a background thread.